# How to check for the existence of a response header in Nginx rules?

Tags: nginx, http, http-headers

Setting up the rewriting rules for the **request** proved to be quite easy in Nginx. For the **response**, not so much (at least, not for me). I want to strip the Content-Type header from the response if the Content-Length header of the response isn't set. I have the [NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) installed, so that should allow me to remove the header, but I can't seem to find a way to check for the existence of the Content-Length header of the response using a rule in Nginx's configuration. Any suggestions on how to do this would be most appreciated!

Comment: Someone did warn you that this is generally a bad idea, right? Omitting `Content-Type` in the HTTP response basically gives the recipient [carte blanche to do whatever it wants](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1), and you may not be able to predict that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like someone asked this on Stack Overflow, and there is a variable for each sent header called $sent_http_my_custom_header.

See https://web.archive.org/web/20140606142058/http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24sent_http_HEADER for the details.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431496/nginx-read-custom-header-from-upstream-server

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like the following in a `location` block:

```
if ($sent_http_content_length ~ '') {
    more_clear_headers Content-Type
    ...
}
```

See [$sent_http_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_sent_http_)

(Disclaimer: I haven't tried this; I just dug through the docs because I found the question interesting. This may or may not work)

Comment: `if` only applies to incoming client requests, you can't use upstream response headers in conditions because the response hasn't been received yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is a variable `$content_length` that according the [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20101029053628/http://wiki.nginx.org:80/HttpCoreModule#.24content_length) is *equal to line Content-Length header of request*. You probably can do

```
if ($content_length = 0) {
    do stuff with header
}
```

I am not sure what value $content_length will assume, or even if it will exist if the header is absent, but you may use that as a starting point to the solution.

Comment: This variable contains the Content-Length of the request, not the response. So unfortunately, it doesn't really help me.

Comment: Oh you right... :\

Comment: Right now, documentation link to wiki returns 404, good urls don't change they say :( Also note that nginx says that [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) you have been warned ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well checking for the nonexistence of something is always a problem... but....

I generally telnet to the port nginx is listening on and make a hand crafted http repsonse:

```
telnet www.stackoverflow.com 80
Trying 69.59.196.211...
Connected to stackoverflow.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
host: www.stackoverflow.com

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 30 Jul 2010 14:31:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://stackoverflow.com/index.html
Content-Length: 158

<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://stackoverflow.com/index.html">here</a></body>
```

You can also use dump header options to curl or wget. For example wget supports:

```
   -S
   --server-response
       Print the headers sent by HTTP servers and responses sent by FTP
       servers.
```

Lastly, [custom logging](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html) might let you add specific response headers, for example:

```
log_format up_head '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $request '
  'upstream_http_content_type $upstream_http_content_type';
```

Comment: Oh I am not so sure this is what you wanted... are you looking to verify what you have done works or how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear in my question. I want to know how to configure it, I already know how to see if it works ;)

Thank you for your reply though!

Comment: I probably just read too fast.